# difficult to know whether files got synchronized or not in a cloud service

Tags: release-hera, icons, dropbox

I am using pCloud and Dropbox for uploading my files. Both services are installed in my computer running elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera. Whenever I add files in any of the service provider folder, there are no signs or tick marks showing the file is uploaded or not. Also, no icons for pCloud or Dropbox are shown in the menu bar of the desktop.

Comment: You'll have to install https://github.com/Lafydev/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana in order to get indicators in wingpanel. This also works with the upcoming release.

Comment: But that will only show the indicator. To What about files that I am putting in cloud service folder. There is literally no indication whether the file is syncing or already got uploaded. I don't get why elementary Devs removed such crucial feature.

Comment: I tried but can't get even get the indicators for Dropbox and pCloud.